# Page Not Pulling From Correct Category?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I need the page below to pull from a certain category. I'm not sure how to do it...in other words when the page is pulled up it will pull all the posts from one category and that category only.

Not sure what to add or where to add it? The category is "For Sale"

http://ampmproperties.com/for-lease-orange-county

```
<?php
/**
 *  Template Name: For Sale
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="container">
    <div class="left_sirebar">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
        <div id="content" role="main">
            <?php $args = array(  'posts_per_page' => 3 );
                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                        if ($count==1)
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                        }

                       echo '<td><div class="For Sale">';
                        echo '<div class="heading_div"><h2 class="entry-title">';
                            the_title();
                            echo '</div></h2>';
                        echo '<div class="entry-content">';

                            echo '<div class="desc">';
                            the_excerpt();
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div></div></td>';

                        if($count==$number_of_columns)
                        {
                        echo "</tr>"; 
                        $count=0;
                        }   
                        $count++;

                        endwhile;
                    ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: A little confusing.... So you need this page to grab posts from a category and then display them? Or to pull this page from a category and then pull posts? Clarification would help.

Comment: so sorry...I was wanting the above page to pull posts from the "for sale" category.

Comment: And then display them on the above page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the category name to your arguments array:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3, 'category_name' => 'For Sale');
```

WordPress' documentation is quite good - whenever you need help with a function like WP_Query, look it up. Your solution was right there in the documentation: [All Posts in a Category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category).

Comment: Thanks Matt..I actually saw the post and the code, but after looking at how you placed it above, showed me that I was working it wrong...thank you so much